# How can I test the setting of a composed object's property using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, oop

Say for example I have two classes within my Rails application - Customer class and a Card class. The Customer class is composed of a Card class i.e. the customer has a card.

I then have a Rails controller with a 'do_something' action defined, which will initialise a new instance of Customer (which in-turn will internally create a new instance of Card) using the params passed in on the POST.

The number of the card is then set as follows:

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController
    def do_something
        customer = Customer.new params
        customer.card.number = params[:card_number]
        ...
    end
end
```

How is this assignment of the card number tested in an RSpec test? Ideally, if 'should_receive_chain' existed we could write:

```
describe MyController do
    describe "POST 'do_something'" do
        it "should set card number"
            params = { :card_number => '1234' }
            card_mock.should_receive_chain(:card, :number).with '1234'
            post :do_something
        end
    end
end
```

Any ideas? Perhaps the fact that it can't be tested easily is a code smell, and maybe I should create a setter method on the Customer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think you are testing this at the wrong level. If you are wed to setting the card number in a separate statement then it might be better to create a function to help with this.

```
class Customer
  def self.new_with_card_number(params, number)
    customer = new(params)
    customer.card.number = number
    customer
  end
end

describe Customer do
  it 'creates a card with a number' do
    customer = described_class.new_with_card_number({}, '1234')
    customer.card.number.should == '1234'
  end
end
```

You could then change your controller to:

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController
  def do_something
    customer = Customer.new_with_card_number(params, params[:card_number])
  end
end
```

A simpler solution might be to simply name the parameter in your form so that setting the card number is done automatically:

```
params[:customer][:card_attributes][:card_number]
```

You could then just change the call to `customer = Customer.new(params)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Customer model to add `accepted_nested_attributes_for :card` and change the controller action to

```rb
class ShopController < ApplicationController
  def do_something
    customer = Customer.create params[:customer]
    ...
  end
end
```

then your spec can look like

```rb
describe ShopController do
  describe 'POST /do_something' do
    it "sets the card's card number" do
      post :do_something, :customer => 
                              {
                                :card_attributes => {:card_number => '1234'}
                              }
      Customer.last.card.number.should == '1234'
    end
  end
end
```